# Postgresql / php

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to get id of current inserted row after executing insertion query.

p.s.: I'm using postgresql database.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that by "id" you mean a column which is primary key and also is declared SERIAL then you need to add a [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) to the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO <table>  (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING id;
```

And in PHP you can treat this statement as a normal query which returns one row.

Comment: when this query is executed "INSERT INTO contacts (title,name,job_title,phone,email) VALUES ('tes','test s/w','0102365478','aa@hotmail.com','123') RETURNING id;" it result the error: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"

Comment: Which probably means you're using older version (<8.2) of Postgres which does not support RETURNING. If possible upgrade.

Comment: is there any solutions??
i tried currval() method but this error is appeared : "Query failed: ERROR: currval of sequence "contacts_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session"

Comment: Please provide details - server version, description of the table(s) involved and the exact command sequence you tried.

Answer (score 0):

In PG7 it was [pg_last_oid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-oid.php), the docs there explain pretty clearly how to get the last id from newer version of PG.

Comment: when this query is executed "INSERT INTO contacts (title,name,job_title,phone,email) VALUES ('tes','test s/w','0102365478','aa@hotmail.com','123') RETURNING id;"

it result the error: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURNING"

Comment: I think that should be comment to garrow's or Milen A. Radev's answers

Answer (score 0):

From the Postgres documentation

> Insert a single row into table distributors, returning the sequence number generated by the DEFAULT clause:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'XYZ Widgets') RETURNING did;
> ```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-insert.html